# Good Php Framework for strong security

Tags: php, security, codeigniter, web-applications, frameworks

I'm trying to choose a framework that provides really good security of web applications, protects against as much of OWASP Top-10 as possible, such as:

- Sql Injection
- XSS
- CSRF
- Authentication
- Authorization
- etc.

the thing is I've tried researching really heavily:
Cakephp, Zend, Yii, Code Igniter, Kohana and some have *basic* authentication, maybe a little authorization, but nothing for any application that needs solid code-security.

Is most of the vulnerability types above currently secured by only writing custom code in these frameworks?

This is kinda my first experience with using frameworks, everything up til this point has been custom php web apps. My whole thought for php-frameworks was it was going to be *easy* to protect against these vulnerabilities, given it isn't *natively*, why use one? Or is there a framework out there I'm not looking at which is better than those listed above for strong web app security? Thanks

Comment: At the end of the day, it's up to you to secure your app. There is not really such a thing as automatic security.

Comment: Codeigniter has built in Injection, XSS, CSRF. Authentication and Authorization are sort of application specific so writing a library to cover them would be almost pointless wouldn't it?

Comment: I know its not automatic, but a framework is there to support...

Comment: I think you might be asking too much from the framework.  All of these have tools that make it easier to protect against these things.  Sql injection protection is inherent in the database abstraction layers that they provide.  XSS and CSRF are better protected by using the form and request objects that they provide.  Authentication and Authorization tend to be left intentionally broad because they are usually very specific to an application.

Comment: @RickCalder No it wouldn't. Come on, it's been many years already, and Codeigniter guys are still repeating that lie? Try any other framework and you'll see how you can have authentication and authorization out of the box.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Security cannot be applied to an application like some veneer. Each kind of a security problem is dealt with in some other way, and most of PHP frameworks provide tools to write secure code:

- Fighting HTML injection / XSS requires the use of a template engine
  (like Twig) that escapes values by default or a component-driven
  approach to displaying HTML. No framework
  will help you, if you allow people to upload their files and have
  them served from your own domain (you have to use a separate domain
  for that);
- You can avoid SQL injection by using db helpers that escape query
  parameters; each framework you mentioned provides those (and of
  course you can use plain PDO);
- You can fight CSRF by using session-bound tokens. Each framework
  offers some solution. In each case, however, you have to assist the
  framework in some way (by adding a token to each form or by using a
  form abstraction provided by the framework).

So in a way - yes, you have to think about security. I don't think any PHP framework could do anything more that they already do, unless there is a major paradigm shift that lets us design applications by dragging colorful boxes across the screen, not touching dirty, insecure things like HTML or SQL. What kind of support would you expect?

Comment: Great comment and food for thought here fdreger  ! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'd also say try CodeIgniter.

- Sql-Injection - If you use the active record pattern in CodeIgniter you're secure
- XSS - It's a config value in config.php
- CSRF - Also a config value in config.php
- Login etc. - There are libraries for that like https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/SimpleLoginSecure

Also CodeIgniter is easy to use if you're working with a framework for the first time and has a great user guide which is really easy to understand.

**Edit:** Since I'm still getting upvotes here in 2019, please check https://laravel.com/

Comment: If I saw your answer earlier, I would have given it the check :) I think im gonna roll with codeigniter :)

Answer (score 1):

The key vulnerabilities you mention happen in different and sometimes multiple layers and are often dependent on the context of what youre doing so a lot of them will offer the facilities to protect against this stuff but you have to make use of it.

For example both Symfony (1.x and 2) and Zend Framework have a form component/sub-framework that implments CSRF out of the box. But that doesnt mean its turned on by default (symfony's is... dont recall if zf's is or not). Same thing with XSS when we talk about the output escaping side in the view layer.

Now when it comes to framework preference for big apps i personally like Symfony 1.x and Symfony2, Zend Framework 1.x (not going to mention zf2 because i havent even played with it yet). For simple things i like Silex (based on Symfony Components).